# include/require обрабатываются до начала выполнения кода?

Tags: php

include/require обрабатываются до начала выполнения кода?

Comment: ........типтого

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а что за многоточия?

Comment: лимит на символы в комментах

Comment: Навряд ли. Как они могут обработаться до начала выполнения, если, например, путь в них задан через переменную.

Comment: @Visman Т.е. include/require не обрабатываются до начала выполнения кода? А включаются и обрабатываются по мере его исполнения?

Comment: Да, я так считаю.

Comment: Итааак, победил Vismaaan!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'nonexistent.php';
// Warning: include(nonexistent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...
// Warning: include(): Failed opening 'nonexistent.php' for inclusion...
```

---

```
<?php
if (false) {
    include 'nonexistent.php'; // Ошибки не вызвало.
}
```

Следовательно, `include` не обрабатывается до начала выполнения кода, несмотря на распространённое заблуждение.